# Why i can not login with jsoup?

Tags: java, authentication, jsoup

I am trying to make java log into a website (discord).

I want it to open my browser and log on. Then it must log out again.

But it does not work.

My code:

```
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class HttpUrlConnectionExample {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup
          .connect("https://discordapp.com/app")
          .method(Connection.Method.GET)
          .execute();

        Document doc = loginForm.parse();
        String csrf = doc.select("input[name=csrf]").val();
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://discordapp.com/app")
                .data("email", "myemail")
                .data("pasword", "mypass")
                .data("login", "loginform")
                .data("csrf", csrf)
                .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();
        String body = response.body();
        if(body.contains("Welcome")){
            System.out.println("Password incorrect!");
        } else if(body.contains("Gebruikersnaam werd niet gevonden.")){
            System.out.println("Not found username!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Login successfully!");          
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "It just does not work." Tell us how. Show any errors or messages.

Comment: I dont get a error. It says login successfully but i have set a wrong password

Comment: You should clearly state in your question what you are trying to do, what you tried, and what results you get. You can [edit] the question at any time. BTW, SO is a terrible debugger. Learning to debug your own code is a great skill. Hint: ask yourself what happens if the body is empty? Bonus: how would you check to see if body was empty, or what it happens to be while testing?

Comment: Something tells me that scraping the text of the result is not really how you would like to check if you are logged in... maybe you need to take a step back and see what others are doing: https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/212889058-Discord-s-Official-API If you must scrape, then be aware of the limitations of doing so.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

`jsoup` is a HTML parser and does not have a javascript engine, therefore it can't execute any javascript which is potentially executed before a user can log in.

If this is the case you'll have to resort to a library which supports javascript. One such as HtmlUnit or Selenium.